# StackLayout inside StackLayout creates overflow

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a menu and this is the scene:

[image]

(I'm just hiding the items names)

So this is the code:

```
public Menu(List<Document> documents, MenuItem parent) {
        ParentItem = parent;

        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical;
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        Spacing = 0;
        Margin = new Thickness(0);
        Padding = new Thickness(0);

        if (documents.Count > 0)
            foreach (Document doc in documents)
                AddItem(new MenuItem(doc, this));
    }

public MenuItem(Document doc, Menu parent) {
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical;
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
        Spacing = 0;
        Margin = new Thickness(0);
        Padding = new Thickness(0);

        Document = doc;

        Parent = parent;
        Head = new MenuItemHead(doc);
        var bdy = new StackLayout() {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            Spacing = 0,
            Margin = new Thickness(0),
            Padding = new Thickness(15, 0, 0, 0)
        };
        bdy.Children.Add(new Menu(doc.Documents, this));
        Body = bdy;

        Active = false;

        if (!doc.IsFolderOpen) {
            var tapped = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapped.Tapped += (s, e) => {
                bool wasActive = Active;
                parent.CollapseItems();
                if (!wasActive) Show();
            };
            Head.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapped);
        } else {
            if (doc.Documents.Count > 0) {
                var tapped = new TapGestureRecognizer();
                tapped.Tapped += async (s, e) => {
                    await MenuView.Push(new Menu(doc.Documents, this));
                };
                Head.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapped);
            }
        }
    }
```

Why the menu item body is overflowing? I don't get it, maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Microsoft Docs for a [StackLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stack-layout)

You will find out that your StackLayout has a default spacing of 6.

Setting the Spacing to `0` should do the trick for you.

Comment: If you see the code the StackLayout is always set to 0.

Comment: If you check the Code you have also added a Padding `Padding = new Thickness(15, 0, 0, 0)` which could be causing this as the padding is on the left if you look closely

Comment: yes, thats the horizontal padding for the submenus, in the image you can see the left indentation. But all other paddings are to zero, where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: From what i see there is no mistake that i can point out directly but i am confused why are you not using a listview here instead?

Comment: because i need to create infinitly nested submenus and listviews can not be nested

Comment: By nested do you mean something like an [ExpandableListView](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-E4hhhKZJCeg/Ue5q2WSiuJI/AAAAAAAAAko/SO-sfbDN-SM/s1600/e1.png)?

Comment: Yes but i needed the fastest way to do it without creating rendering of the groups, and with an infinite nesting level.

Comment: All of this can be done using Expandable ListViews if you work properly and it will be much faster than what you have come up with(My Opinion)

Comment: Can you please link the repo?

Comment: This is the [guide](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-expendable-listview-app/) and this is the [repo](https://github.com/my-jabin/ExpandableListView-Xamarin)